# Rendering with Emission shaders seems effective in Preview renders, but not in final ones

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I have 2 floor planes with Diffuse shaders, and 2 light planes with Emission shaders. These are effective in Preview mode, but when I render, all the lights seem to be disabled - the render looks dark. Only if I add a White Background in World will I see the object being rendered with some light, *but* the floor light from the planes doesn't seem to be effective.

What could be causing this?

Here's the blend file:

[image]

Comment: Post a blend and/or screenshot and/or describe your problem better. There could be many causes to this.

Comment: I have 2 floor planes set to Diffuse, and 2 light planes set to Emission. These are effective in Preview mode, but when turn to Render mode, all the floors and effect of lighting seem disabled and the render looks dark. Only if I add a White Background in World I will see the object being rendered with some light, BUT the floor planes and light from light planes don't seem to be effective.

Comment: Are you sure the light planes are not hidden in the render?

Comment: very sure. I even try to use all the settings as in the helicopter example that come with Blender 2.74. Kind of strange.

Comment: Beats me... Could you post the blend file, using something like [Blend Exchange](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/630/announcing-blend-exchange-a-new-solution-to-blend-hosting) ?

Comment: thanks, but sorry my design is confidential info. will try with a simple object to duplicate the problem, will be back.

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=190" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/190/)

Comment: Please post relevant information as an edit to the post

Comment: pls help have a look at the file I shared, thanks.

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED:
The Floor Panes and Light Planes each has to be assigned with a layer, and include all these layers during Render mode.
Thanks anyway.

SUGGESTION to BLENDER DEVELOPER:
The Layer Assignment should be shown in the Outliner Window and user should be WARNED for any layers not included in RENDER.

Comment: Somehow, the Floor Panes and Light Planes were NOT AUTOMATICALLY assigned with a layer when created. I strongly suggest a Layer column be added and listed under the Outliner so that it is easily noticed.

Comment: @GoldenForest the real problem is that you are in the Local view , just hit   `/` in the viewport and you 'll be able to render normally